# Find the Cumulative Density Function

Tags: uniform-distribution

[image] are Independently and Identically Distributed.

[image]
[image]

Z=|X-Y|.

Find the PDF of Z.
The joint PDF of this function is 1 as well. Through the graph, I found that the CDF of Z is [image] and PDF is [image: uniform]. However, I am not able to solve it through the joint density function of x,y. What are the limits in which the joint function should be integrated to get the CDF of Z?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the distribution of $|X-Y|$ if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. uniform on $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484835/find-the-distribution-of-x-y-if-x-and-y-are-i-i-d-uniform-on-0-1)

Comment: Yes, thank you so much.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1681363/321264